# Add Styles to document head from the view in Cakephp?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I need to add styles to my style tag in my head section. How can i add to that style tag from the view.

Comment: Why do you want in particular a style and not an external stylesheet? A style in the head section can always be replaced by one.

Comment: It has seance when it is needed to add only few lines of CSS definition for specific element in only certain view.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off from an MVC point of view by putting these style elements in to their own stylesheet, and then inserting the sheet in the way mentioned above.

However if you must use internal CSS, this should work:

```
$this->addScript('extraCSS','<style type="text/css>".foo{color:red;}</style>');
```

`extraCSS` I believe is just an internal name given to the content that gets added to the `$scripts_for_layout` buffer.

This will appear below any JS inclusions, which can be a problem at times.

Comment: `addScript` method of the View may accept one argument, so it is more clearer to write `$this->addScript('<style type="text/css">...</style>')`. It works. I tested in CakePHP 1.3

Answer (score 0):

See all about adding css files using the HTML Helper here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1437/css

Make sure you have `$scripts_for_layout` in the head of your layout to have cake put scripts there automatically (see the third example).

**EDIT:**

For style tags, see here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1440/style

Otherwise, CakePHP uses simple PHP as the templating language in the view - so just write it using that.

Some example code and further explanation of what you'd like to do would also be helpful.

Comment: tats not what i want. i need to add in page style elements. in a style tag